# Sagepay repeat payments using CV2 number

Tags: opayo, pci-compliance

When performing a repeat payment we need to provide the CV2 number because SagePay does not store it. As we are taking the payments automatically (overnight task) it means we need to store the number in our database (as the customer will not be typing it in).

We also store the last 4 digits of the card number and the expiry date for information.

Does any of the above make us non-PCI compliant, or does it not matter because we are not storing the actual card details on our server?

Comment: A *Continuous Authority* merchant account is what you what to use for repeat transactions, this will not require the re-submission of card details.  You should talk to SagPay and ask them.  The answer regarding compliance is something for a QSA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to store the CV2 number post auth. That's a big no-no.

Sage Pay will accept a REPEAT payment (using a CA MID) without the CV2. Your acquiring fee will be based on the fact that you are using a CA

Answer (score 1):

Concur.  Storing the CVV is a big no-no and if the credit card companies suspect you are doing this, they will precipitate a forensic audit (they will send an investigator our to clone your hard drives and will take a forensic look at your database) that will cost your client at least $10k (and a fine, too).  All major, effective payment processors furnish you with an approved method to do recurring payments without presenting CVV on charges after the first, initiating charge when the customer is online and their first charge is checked - the CVV being checked without being stored - research that method and make use of the methods provided - otherwise, the consequences for your client can be rather severe...